# for SOAP xml parsing which framework is better (iOS swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, soap, ios9.1

i am new to soap xml parsing and i have a data like this so how can i send request and get response?? Here is my Schema

```
<xs:element name="Firmalar">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FirmaNo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML) is a very well written library to parse SOAP XMLs. It is iOS 8 and over only.

Alternatively you can use `NSXMLParser` and implement your own parsing mechanism.

Comment: how can i parse this snippet can u do this one for example?  <xs:element name="Firmalar">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirmaNo" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>